# The equivalent of min(x,y) in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, osascript

I've got a working AppleScript which has a *repeat* looking like this:

```
repeat with i from 1 to count windows of proc
    ....
end repeat
```

now I want to change this to *min(2,count windows of proc)*

How would I write this using purely AppleScript? (solution involving Bash etc. are not acceptable, the question is really about how to do this from AppleScript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do it.  You'll have to write the function yourself:

```
on min(x, y)
    if x ≤ y then
        return x
    else
        return y
    end if
end min

...

repeat with i from 1 to min(2, count windows of proc)
    ...
end repeat
```

Note that if you want to use `min` inside of a `tell ...` or `using terms from ...` block, you'll have to call it as `my min(2, count windows of proc)` so that AppleScript knows to look for `min` in the script, not in the terms from the application or what-have-you.

Also, a quick note: the language you're working with is called AppleScript, not OsaScript.  The command-line tool for working with it is called `osascript` because it works with the more generic [Open Scripting Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript#Open_Scripting_Architecture).  Other languages (such as JavaScript) can be OSA components, but realistically speaking, pretty much everybody uses AppleScript.